# Where can I get "DA360C64005E0276" public key for "ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release"?

Tags: 10.10, apt, ppa, launchpad, gnupg

When I apt-get update I get the following error:

`W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DA360C64005E0276`

How to fix this? Where can I find this key to import it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's easy you have to download the PPA GPG key :

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver
>   keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
>   005E0276

and then :

`sudo aptitude update` or `sudo apt-get update` again.

- [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey-without-terminal)

Comment: What causes this problem in the first place?

Comment: @Toki Tahmidthe problem begin that when you want to include a PPA repository in your sources.list This enables your Ubuntu system to verify that the packages in the PPA have not been interfered with since they were built. and this PPA is Signing. more information -> https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware

Comment: @Toki See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey-without-terminal

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small script a while back that imports all missing GPG keys automatically so if you ever come upon errors like this, check it out: [launchpad-getkeys](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/import-missing-gpg-keys-even-behind.html).