# How to fix GPG error for extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release?

Tags: apt, gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Some days ago my `apt-get update` has suddenly began to throw

```
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key
```

As far as I understand, this is about a brand Ubuntu repository, not something I've added (actually I were not adding any repositories and/or changing apt settings those days).
How to fix this? The OS is XUbuntu 11.10 "Oneric Ocelot" x86.

I've tried

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

and

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3E5C1192
```

neither seems to help.

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors , or http://askubuntu.com/questions/20725/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key , or http://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center , or http://askubuntu.com/questions/27254/where-can-i-get-da360c64005e0276-public-key-for-ppa-launchpad-net-maverick-re